# Combined Procedure for Triggers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

How would I create a stored procedure that is capable of taking in a flag value such as (1,2,3) where 1=insert, 2=delete, 3=update.

So for example if flag is 1, the procedure will do insert, and so forth.

I know how to create stored procedures and have already made and tested my triggers, but I can't find any examples of this and dont know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `if` seems like it would be useful.

Comment: I would create three different stored procedures for each of insert, delete and update. Would you create a traditional function in eg C, C# of Java that does all of the three operations? I know I wouldn't! [Separation of Concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use normal If else statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <ProcedureName> (@Flag int)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Flag = 1)--INSERT 
    BEGIN
        <Insert statement>
    END
    ELSE IF(@Flag = 2) --DELETE
    BEGIN
        <Delete statement>
    END
    ELSE IF (@Flag = 3) --UPDATE
    BEGIN
        <Update statement>
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CTEs and conditions.

To give you an example of what I mean:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test (_flag integer) RETURNS void AS
$func$

WITH delete AS
(DELETE FROM
atable
WHERE
_flag = 1),

insert AS
(INSERT INTO
atable (acolumn)
SELECT
'Hello World'
WHERE
_flag = 2)

UPDATE
atable
SET
acolumn = 'Hello World'
WHERE
_flag = 3;

$func$
LANGUAGE sql COST 100 STRICT;
```

You'll notice each statement has its own flag-checking condition.